Запуск батника для чтения файлы программой не установленной на ПК
Есть рабочая папка с программой. которую приходится часто подкидывать на рабочие станции клиентов. Там находится исполняемая программа, которая создает перезаписываемой файл. Путь до папки на станции клиента может быть разным.
После каждой команды создается файл "12" (файл не имеет расширения) который мне нужно открыть, потом, перезаписать его другой командой и снова открыть.
Часть кода выглядит так:
@echo off
load 2
pause
start notepad++ "%~dp012."
pause
load 16
start notepad++ "%~dp012."

Как сделать, чтобы файл всегда открывался через notepad++ на рабочей станции?

Николай, невозможно использовать неустановленную программу. Можно только добавить проверок, и выводить уведомление: "Notepad++ не установлен. Пожалуйста, установите Notepad++ для открытия файла." И то, я сейчас столкнулась с проблемой: кодировка в консоли (пытаясь это реализовать). Уточните свой вопрос, приведите к реализуемой задаче.

Допустим, что в 99% случаев, у клиента стандартная винда с предустановленным нотепадом какой-нибудь версии. Путь размещения мне неизвестен. Есть способ реализовать код, чтобы файл  открывался установленным ридером на ПК клиента?

Ну, это вообще фантастика.

@НиколайКудряшов Для 99% случаев (у клиента стандартная винда с предустановленным нотепадом какой-нибудь версии), можно попытаться решить (я проработаю пути решения - позже дам ответ). Вам надо поправить вопрос.

Точно. Поправил. Спасибо.

@AnnaBazueva (Николай, невозможно использовать неустановленную программу.) А как же портабл версии программ? Что если вместе с файлами подкинуть портативную версию текст ридера и в батнике прописать открытие файла через exe файл ридера? Такое возможно?

@НиколайКудряшов Ну, это ведь программа не требующая установки... (подкинули - считай установили). А к чему такие манипуляции!? И почему Вы постоянно используете слово - "подкинуть"? Вообще-то клиент должен знать требуемое окружение.

@AnnaBazueva Никакого криминала) Партнерская программа которую копирую на станцию клиента необходима для функционирования нашего же оборудования. Программа разными командами создает перезаписываемый файл с разным содержанием. Текст этого файла мне необходимо просматривать и открывать его каждый раз средствами клиентского ПО ... ну такое себе занятие (Выбрать ридер, указать кодировку, шрифт и прочее) а делать надо это часто. Вот и ищу способ упросить процесс.

@НиколайКудряшов Никакого криминала) – это хорошо! А сколько стоит Ваше время!?

@AnnaBazueva Оно бесценно) Но я Вас услышал) В любом случае, Большое спасибо за оказанную помощь, Вы мне и так уже помогли достаточно. Больше не потревожу) Еще раз спасибо. Пошел перед женой извиняться, за то что ночью стучу по клаве и не даю уснуть))

Без расширения вы не сможете ассоциировать файл с каким-либо приложением.
Вы можете скопировать файл и придать имени какое-то расширение. Тогда можно ассоциировать это расширение с Нотепадом++:

Из командной строки вы можете создать или изменить ассоциацию файла с программой. Например, вы хотите чтобы все файлы с расширением tx1 открывались с помощью notepad++.exe. Сначала нужно создать ассоциацию расширения .tx1 с новым типом файлов tx1file.

assoc .tx1=tx1file


Укажите программу, которая должна использоваться по умолчанию при открытии файлов с расширением tx1.

ftype tx1file="%programfiles(x86)%\"Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"

В команде выше задайте необходимый путь к npp.

у файла "12" нет расширения, но его можно просмотреть через блокнот или ворд

Ещё раз "Как сделать, чтобы файл файл всегда открывался через notepad++" - никак. Без расширения вы не сможете ассоциировать файл с каким-либо приложением. Открывать его можно где угодно, но нельзя сделать так, чтобы даблкликнул его - и он открылся в блокноте, нотепаде++ или где-либо ещё. Вам же это нужно?

Вы же сами содаёте этот файл? Сделайте ему расширение txt. Или любое, и ассоциируйте его с Нотепад++.

Нет, этот файл создает партнерская программа, мне нужен быстрый способ открытия этого перезаписываемого файла без поиска нужного ридера и выбора в нем нужной кодировки на рабочей станции клиента

Ответ так и остаётся - нет. Без расширения - нет. Скопируйте его с расширением.

Допустим. У файла изначально нет расширения, тогда нужно, после создания файла сделать его копию, присвоить копии расширение, открыть копию, следующей командой снова перезаписать файл, сделать копию и т.д., сколько нужно? Как будет выглядеть такой код?

"Следующей командой снова перезаписать файл" - это ещё зачем? Сделали копию один раз, и всё. Конечно, если файл меняется, его снова нужно копировать.

Вообще, сделайте батник "notepad++ "%~dp012."" и скажите пользователям, что чтобы посмотреть файл, нужно запустить этот батник.

А код ассоциации assoc .tx1=tx1file сработает если изначально расширения нет, а-ля assoc .=txt

@НиколайКудряшов Так ты попробуй, если слов не понимаешь.
